# When are C# keywords not reserved?

Tags: c#, syntax, reserved-words

I just found myself absent-mindedly using `from` as an identifier.

I realise that it is possible to use `@` to escape identifier names and as such use reserved words, but I don't understand why in this case I got no warning or error.

I have no desire to use reserved words for anything but their intended purpose, but I don't want to make a similar mistake again and would like to know the rationale behind having language keywords that are not reserved in certain circumstances.

Comment: some keywords where added after a lot of code has been written, like the keyword 'from' from Linq. It could break a lot of already existing code if it was impossible to use it. Also, as mentioned, some keywords are only in certain contexts.

Comment: For some analysis of the various rules for when keywords have particular meanings see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/keywords/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some keywords are only reserved in certain contexts, e.g., the `partial` in `partial class`.

See the "contextual keywords" under [this topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).

Comment: So it would appear, but what is the rationale and where is it documented in the spec?

Comment: +1 Exactly. The parser can tell the difference between `var from = ...` and `var q = from ...`.

Comment: The rationale is in the MSDN link I posted; to quote: "Generally, as new keywords are added to the C# language, they are added as contextual keywords in order to avoid breaking programs written in earlier versions."

Comment: Indeed, it did occur to me after writing that this must be the case, but I'm glad to now have a clearer notion of precisely how it is defined.  Thanks as well to others who made the same point.

Answer (score 4):

The C# team specifically tries to avoid creating new reserved keywords in the language.  Any new keyword added means that it automatically breaks existing code which used that keyword as an identifier.  Hence whenever possible C# will use a contextual keyword to minimize or eliminate the possibility of breaking existing code.

A contextual keyword is one that is only a keyword when used in a specific context like `from`, `partial`, `var`, etc ...  That context does not include identifiers :)

I do not believe there's been a new keyword added since C# 2.0 (not even sure 2.0 added one)

Answer (score 3):

*from* is a 'contextual keyword'.  Lots of those in C#, they only behave like a keyword when they are used in a certain context.  The big advantage is that adding such a contextual keyword to the language won't break existing code.

You'll find them listed in the 2nd table in this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).  Yup, *from* is there.

Answer (score 2):

They are not *reserved* when they are *contextual* ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)):

> A contextual keyword is used to
>   provide a specific meaning in the
>   code, but it is not a reserved word in
>   C#. Some contextual keywords, such as
>   partial and where, have special
>   meanings in two or more contexts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the underlying question:

All keywords added after C# 1 are contextual.  This avoids breaking changes.

Almost all C# 1 keywords are reserved, except for accessor keywords (`add`, `remove`, `get`, and `set`).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the C# keywords are always reserved. Some, as you found out, is only reserved in some contexts. They are called contextual keywords. I believe this is a way to better ensure backwards compatibility.

The reasoning is that `from` was a perfectly acceptable variable name in C# 2. C# 3 added LINQ, and they needed keywords for it. In order to maintain maximum compatibility, `from` was added as a contextual keyword.